# Can't use custom classes in aidl

Tags: android, aidl

I have two applications which communicate via aidl interface. Everything works when I use basic types like String or int, however according to [this](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/android/android-4.0/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html#parcelable) I should be able to use custom types too. However code (even very simplified) **doesn't compile** in my case.

This is how it looks like:

app/src/main/aidl/edu/cat/ion/**TestClass.java**:

```
package edu.cat.ion;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public final class TestClass implements Parcelable {

    public TestClass() {
    }

    protected TestClass(Parcel in) {
    }

    public static final Creator<TestClass> CREATOR = new Creator<TestClass>() {
        @Override
        public TestClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TestClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestClass[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }
}
```

app/src/main/aidl/edu/cat/ion/**TestClass.aidl**:

```
package edu.cat.ion;

parcelable TestClass;
```

At this point code compiles but when in some other class I just do:

```
import edu.cat.ion.TestClass;
```

I get:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> import edu.cat.ion.TestClass;

Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: Where is your some other class where you are importing is located?

Comment: It's under app/src/main/java/edu/cat/ion/OtherClass.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the error because of path mismatch for `TestClass.java` file.

Currently your `TestClass.java` is located under `aidl` folder which other `java` classes are not able to find.

Hence move your

> app/src/main/aidl/edu/cat/ion/TestClass.java

file to `java` folder.

> app/src/main/java/edu/cat/ion/TestClass.java

Comment: @LLL  I'm glad to have been able to help  :)

Comment: Your sir, saved my life.